# Access elements of 2D array with absolute element number

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a 2-Dimensional array whose elements I typically want to access like this:

```
val = my_array[row][col];
```

But I also have need to access elements using their absolute index from time to time, where the row and column are not known.  The "absolute" index of a given element can be computed as follows:

```
abs_idx = row*numCols + col;
```

I am thinking of achieving this as follows

```
mydatatype *my_array_abs = new mydatatype[numRows*numCols];
mydatatype **my_array = new mydatatype*[numRows];
for (int ii=0; ii<numRows; ii++)
{
    my_array[ii] = &my_array_abs[ii*numCols];
}
```

Is this an appropriate way to achieve my goal, or should I expect to run into any problems or inefficiencies?

Comment: You also need to allocate memory to `my_array`.

Comment: Pardon me but I can't seen in your posted code that you have allocated memory to `my_array`.

Comment: @Learner You are absolutely right.  I revoked my comment after I realized what you were saying. I had overlooked that point.  In throwing out some example code, I didn't think that part through all the way.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you want you need to change your line:

```
mydatatype *my_array;
```

**To:**

```
mydatatype **my_array = new mydatatype*[numRows] ;
```

**Note:** I see only one issue with this approach that, you required continuous memory chunk.
Otherwise your approach is perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes.  I overlooked the fact that I needed to allocate a space for those pointers, even if they are referring to memory that has already been allocated.  I am tempted to edit this fix into my question though, because the purpose of my question was more about whether this was an efficient way to do this, rather than *how* to do it.

Comment: If memory is not a issue for you then this approach is definitely efficient because you have continuous memory. And access to the contiguous memory is faster than the non contiguous memory.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to use std::vector to avoid all the hazards of raw arrays:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
typedef int mydatatype;
typedef std::vector<std::vector<mydatatype> > myvectortype;

int numCols = 10;
int numRows = 100;

mydatatype& at_absolute(myvectortype& v, int index) {
  return v[index / numRows][index % numRows];
}

int main() {
  myvectortype my_array(numRows, std::vector<mydatatype>(numCols, 0));

  my_array[1][2] = 31;
  std::cout << at_absolute(my_array, 102) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I like the idea, but it seems like it might be less efficient because each array access operation costs an additional two division operations.  Any thoughts?  I guess I should mention that efficiency is critical because I am implementing a real-time DSP system, so I am looking to shave off MIPS where possible.

Comment: I guess a single dimension array might be more efficient, with an "at_row_col" access function (probably makes more sense too).